# Color Depth React Native

Tags: react-native, color-depth

Is there a way to get the color depth of the device using React Native?
The Javascript window object has no such property (at least not in RN) and window.screen is undefined. In the Dimensions (RN Import), there is no property for color depth.

Thanks